# Can't Open Bkash App On Press React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to open my bkash app(installed on my device) when button gets clicked. But it redirects me to the play store although the app is installed on my device.

<Pressable onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bKash.customerapp')}/>

Comment: You have to implement deep linking

Comment: How can I can do that? is there any demo?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/

Comment: How can I  get host name? How can I get bKash deep link ?. The documentation shows how to configure my app with deep linking though but I need to open the bKash app.

Comment: basically your server redirect the link to app or play store, if you don't have access to backend you can configure it using Firebase e dynamic links https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links

Comment: The link that I mentioned redirects the app to the play store with front end , but i want to open the app directly, not in play store.